# Why Stream.sorted method doesn't throw NullPointerException as List.sort method when given null values?

Tags: java

```
public class ToSort {
    private String sortBy;

    public ToSort(String sortBy) {
        this.sortBy = sortBy;
    }
    public String getSortBy() {
        return sortBy;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Comparator<ToSort> comp = Comparator.comparing(ToSort::getSortBy);

        ToSort o1 = new ToSort("TEST");
        ToSort o2 = new ToSort(null);

        List list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(o1);
        list.add(o2);

        list.stream().sorted(comp); // ok
        list.sort(comp); // NullPointerException
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1750)
    at com.oxand.simeox.model.pojo.ToSort.main(ToSort.java:28)
```

Why Stream.sorted method doesn't throw NullPointerException as List.sort method when given null values and using the same comparator?

Comment: Streams are lazy, i.e. The line `list.stream().sorted(comp);` is never excuted since it doesn't have a terminal operation to complete a stream. In generall an intermediate Stream doesn't do anything. If you add a terminal operation like `collect()`, `count()`, `forEach()` ... you will see the same behavior and will throw a NPE.

Comment: Oh yes, i forgot that is necessary a terminal operation to complete a stream. I confirm, i executed for example `list.stream().sorted(comp).collect(Collectors.toList())` and i got a  NPE.

Answer (score 1):

The  [java 8 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) says about stream:

> Stream operations are divided into intermediate (Stream-producing) operations and terminal (value- or side-effect-producing) operations. Intermediate operations are always lazy.

Stream.sorted is an intermediate operation that return a new stream and stream are always lazy. If a terminal operation, such as Stream.forEach or Stream.Collect is executed, the stream pipeline will be consumed and the same behavior (NullPointerException) will be observed.